# Problem with DATE type category in SSRS Stacked Bar chart

Tags: reporting-services, rdl

I've defined a simple stacked bar (column) chart in Visual Studio 2017 for SSRS SQLServer 2014 as follows

[image: VS rdl for stacked bar chart]

The 'StartDate' values are the dates of the first day of a week. I'm setting the x-axis option to use them as 'category' (as opposed to scalar). All straightforward enough. However, with the following dataset, for example,

[image: Sample dataset]

The resultant chart comes out as

[image: Sample chart]

It seems to be interpolating the dates back to zero, even though I've configured the axis to treat them as 'category'.
If I change my query to return the dates formatted as a string prepended with some character it works fine ...

[image: sample chart with non-date values]

But, obviously having that prepended character is messy and shouldn't be necessary.
What am I missing? Is there some setting that I should be changing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem was caused because of an early mistake I made. I had set the 'StartDate' field as the 'Category' field in the series properties

[image: Incorrect configuration]

If anyone would care to comment on the difference between providing a 'Category field' here and having a field defined for the 'Category group' that would be appreciated.